# How to find the value for which this matrix is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am supposed to find for what values the following matrix is invertible I have the following matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    a  & a  & 1\\
    a  & a-1 & 2\\
    2  & 0 &  2
\end{bmatrix}$$

So after calculating the determinant I end up with determinant = 2. But where do I go from here? Normally when calculating the determinant I have an expression like $(x-2)(x-3)$ and I can easily see that that matrix is invertible when $x$ is not 2, 3 or 0. But what do I do with the matrix above when the determinant is 2? How do I find the value for which it is (or isn't) invertible?

Comment: If the determinant is 2 (i don't believe it) your matrix is always invertible independent of $a$

Comment: @the_architect, I didn't believe it either at first but it's correct.  Easiest to calculate with cofactors along the bottom row.  All terms with $a$ cancel.

Comment: I got 2, and I checked with a determinant calculator and it is indeed 2. But my answer sheet says it is invertible for all numbers except when a = -2?

Comment: @OfeliavanAnalhard then your answer sheet must be wrong

Comment: The answer sheet is indeed wrong.  Try substituting $a = -2$ into the matrix and then calculate the determinant.  You'll still get $2$.

Comment: @adjan I doubt that, then it also asks me to find the inverse for all the a:s where an inverse exists. Im very confused...

Comment: @OfeliavanAnalhard There is no doubt. There exists an inverse for any $a$.

Comment: Why doubt it?  It's easy to verify by hand and with a determinant calculator.  If $a = -2$ then the matrix is still invertible.  These things (answer sheets) do have mistakes sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

If you've found that the determinant is $2$, then this means that the determinant will always be $2$ regardless of the value of $a$.  Therefore all possible values of $a$ give you an invertible matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse is
$$\begin{bmatrix}a-1&-a&\dfrac{a+1}2\\2-a&a-1&-\dfrac a2\\1-a&a&-\dfrac a2\end{bmatrix}.$$

It is indeed defined for all $a$.